# Leave-one-out cross-validation for negative binomial

Tags: cross-validation, negative-binomial-distribution

I've just started working with the GLM negative binomial and I was wondering if it's possible to carry out a leave-one-out cross-validation for negative binomial GLM as I'm having troubles doing it with R using {boot}. My variables are standardized!Can it be a problem?
Any help will be very very appreciated! Sorry if this question is a bit prosy..Thanks in advance!

Mau

Comment: I see no reason it can't be done.  What specific problems are you having?